# Entity Component System Circular Dependency or Unknown Size

Tags: c++, size, entity, c++14, circular-dependency

I am trying to develop an entity component system where an EntityManager class Manages the entities and their components. I am using vectors to manage the components. Their is a vector for each type of Component, that way I always know what type of component I'm working with and what kind of operations the component is capable of and to keep my memory contiguous (as opposed to having one large vector of pointers).

To create vectors for each component type the compiler needs to know the size of each component class, so I find that I need to include every Component in the EntityManager header.

Unfortunately some of the components need to use the EntityManager to access other data, so in order to use some of the EntityManagers static methods I need to include EntityManager in the component class.

And there in lies the problem. I have created a circular dependency that I can't think of a way to break. I need the complete classes so that EntityManager knows the size of the components and the components need the EntityManagers methods so forward declaration isn't possible.

Thankfully I know stack overflow is full of people a lot smarter than me who may know some nifty tricks that could help me work around this problem if at all possible.

Here is a minimal(ish) and verifiable sample of my code:

EntityManager.h

```
#pragma once
#include "RigidStaticComponent.h"
#include "RigidDynamicComponent.h"
#include "Entity.h"
#include "Transform.h"
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

#define COMPONENTS  X(RigidStaticComponent), X(RigidDynamicComponent)
#define X(ARG) std::vector<ARG>
using ComponentTuple = std::tuple<COMPONENTS>;
#undef X

class EntityManager {
private:
    static ComponentTuple components;
public:
    static vector<Transform> transforms;

    template<class T>
    static auto& Components();

    static Transform& GetTransform(short entityID);
};

template<class T>
auto& EntityManager::Components()
{
    return std::get<std::vector<T>>(components);
}
```

EntityManager.cpp

```
#include "EntityManager.h"

vector<Transform> EntityManager::transforms;

Transform& EntityManager::GetTransform(short entityID) {
    return transforms[entityID];
};
```

RigidbodyComponent.h

```
#pragma once
#include "EntityManager.h"
#include "Entity.h"
#include "Transform.h"
class RigidbodyComponent {
    short entityID;

    //I've commented out the physx objects becuase they require dependancies unrelated to the question
    //I have left it in as an example of how I would use the EntityManager within the component classes

    //physx::PxRigidActor* pxRigid;

    void SetEntity(Entity& _entity) {
        EntityManager::transforms[_entity.transformID]; //This is what I am using instead to produce the ciruclar dependancy for the sake of this sample code
        //pxRigid->setGlobalPose(Transform::ToPx(EntityManager::transforms[_entity->transformID]));
        return;
    }
};
```

RigidStaticComponent.h

```
#pragma once
#include "RigidbodyComponent.h"
class RigidStaticComponent : public RigidbodyComponent {
};
```

RigidDynamicComponent.h

```
#pragma once
#include "RigidbodyComponent.h"
class RigidDynamicComponent : public RigidbodyComponent {
};
```

Transform.h

```
#pragma once
class Transform {
public:
    /*physx::PxVec4 ToPx(glm::vec4 v) {
    return physx::PxVec4(v.x, v.y, v.z, v.w);
    }*/
};
```

Entity.h

```
#pragma once
class EntityManager;

class Entity {
    friend class EntityManager;
private:
    short id;
public:
    unsigned short transformID;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using std::getchar;
int main() {
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is already a fairly large project already so I would like to avoid as much refactoring as possible but as I have said previously I just can't think of an easy solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I am trying to develop an entity component system where an EntityManager class Manages the entities and their components."  I have no idea what that means.  I will take a look at it if you will assemble the pieces.  A [MCVE] needs to be something that can be cut-and-pasted into an IDE, no assembly required.

Comment: @JiveDadson Thank you very much for your interest. I updated my sample so that it can be directly cut and paste to produce the scenario I am encountering. I am not quite certain what you mean by "assemble the pieces" I have to separate the code into different files in order to "include" them and thus create the circular dependency that I am having issues with. If you would like I can upload a zipped visual studio project and send you a link to download it?

Comment: `std::vector<T>` is explicitly allowed to be instantiated with incomplete type `T`. So forward declarations of `RigidStaticComponent` and `RigidDynamicComponent` in `EntityManager.h` should be sufficient. You need to define `EntityManager::components` in `EntityManager.cpp` (the same way you do `EntityManager::transforms`), and of course include the headers there. Further, you can (and probably should) implement `RigidbodyComponent::SetEntity` in a separate source file - then you wouldn't need to include `EntityManager.h` into `RigidbodyComponent.h`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Wow that was amazing simple and some straight up compiler magic right there, that's awesome. Thank you so much.